# Cakephp 3 radio options not selecting

Tags: forms, cakephp, radio-button, cakephp-3.x

I'm having an issue when selecting options for a form. I am using form helper. In a list of options, only the last element can be checked. See below.

view file code as below :

```
<?= $this->Form->create(false) ?>

    <?php foreach ($question->answers as $answers): ?>

        <?php 
        echo $this->Form->radio(
            'answer',
            [
                ['value' => $answers->description, 'text' => $answers->description],

            ]
        );
        ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Next')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

If I have a list of options lets say : Red, Blue, Green in that order, only green will be sent in the request data if it is selected. The others will not be present in the request data even if i select them. It is only the last option that is stored. What could be the problem?

Running cake version 3.2.3

Comment: Essentially the same problem as **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084110/cakephp-formhelper-not-saving-data-from-two-inputs-with-same-name/20084580**. You should be able to answer the question yourself after reading that, the fix is the same in 3.x

Comment: @ndm that worked. Users should also return non-bool values in the value key. Radio options interprets a returned 1 as a "checked".